# Removing all local commits while preserving all the work

Tags: git

My remote repository looks like -

```
A->B->C
```

My local repository looks like -

```
A->B->C->D->E
```

The commits D and E were made by me. I also have some other local changes which have not been committed.
I now want to remove commits D and E, but none of my work should get affected. When I'm done with everything, I want my local repository to look like -

```
A->B->C->X
```

What should I do from here?

Comment: Do you (1) want to undo the changes made by D and E and X is your currently uncommited changes, or  (2) is X the sum of D and E without the uncommited changes, or (3) is X the sum of D, E, and your currently uncommitted changes?

Comment: X is the sum of D,E and uncommitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interactive rebase

```
git stash
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

In the opened editor set:

```
pick <COMMIT D>
squash <COMMIT E>
```

Than pop your stash

```
git stash pop
```

This will make your project like this A->B->C->X(D+E) with uncommited changes.

Comment: Really? After this sequence, X=D+E, but uncommitted changes remain uncommitted. Perhaps add `git commit -a --amend` to include the uncommitted changes.

Comment: Yes, they are still uncommited. If you want to put it into X - your solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git stash` to stash your local uncommitted work and then after you remove commits D and E using `git reset` you can perform `git stash pop` to bring back your uncommitted work from the stash

OR

If you want those commits D and E as a backup for later, you can create a new branch; say `new_branch` by checking out from the current branch

`git checkout -b new_branch`.

Now you have A->B->C->D->E in the new_branch

You can now commit your current work on top of this as commit X. So now it becomes A->B->C->D->E->X

Now you can checkout back to your previous branch, remove commits D and E using `git reset` and then **cherry pick** commit X from new_branch.

Comment: git reset command for removing the last 2 commits?

Comment: You have to perform `git log` and copy the commit hash of the commit C and the perform `git reset --hard <copied commit hash>`

This will reset your tree to commit C. So it would look like this -->  
A->B->C

Comment: I want to preserve work from commits D and E

Comment: As per your question, you wanted to remove commit D and E. When you remove a commit, the work you have performed inside that commit would be removed. 
What do you mean when you say you want to preserve work from commits D and E?

Comment: Remove commits D and E, but have the work in them locally present

Comment: okay. In that case, you need to do this sequentially. 

First you need to run `git reset <commit hash of commit D>` . Now if you check `git status` you can see that all the files and changes of commit E are now available in your local working directory. 

You might have to stash them and again do the same process for commit D by `git reset <commit hash of commit C>`